# Hamburger menu visible for grid sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

## 1. Introduction

I am programming my first website using Bootstrap 3. And I use Html, Css and JavaScript.

## 2. The problem

I have made a hamburger menu which should only be visible in the extra small mobile grid (*1-768px*). The menu works perfect in this extra small grid. But when I scale up the browser window the hamburger menu keeps being visible in the small grid (*769-992px*).

I have tried to fiddle around with my Javascript and searched for answers but with no succes.

[Here is the visual representation of the problem!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88OdD.png)

## 3. My Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
            var e = document.getElementById('hamburgermenu');
            if(e.style.display == 'block') 
                e.style.display = 'none';
            else
                e.style.display = 'block';
            }
    </script>

    <style>
        #hamburgermenu {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1000000; 

            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 50px;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- HTML BUTTON FOR HIDE AND SHOW -->
    <button onclick="toggle_visibility('hamburgermenu');">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- HTML BUTTON FOR HIDE AND SHOW -->

    <!-- HTML MOBILE MENU -->
    <div id="hamburgermenu" >
        <ul class="mobilemenu">
            <li><a href="#">PROJECTEN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SKILLSET</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">STAGE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">OVER MIJ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- END HTML MOBILE MENU -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

inline style (style="display: block;") is still there so #hamburgermenu {display: none;} is useless.

There are many solutions, the easy one is to set a mediaquery with #hamburgermenu {display: none !important;}

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to deal with the visibility issue manually when you use bootsrap.
Bootstrap has special helper classes which can be assigned to html elements in order to manage their visibility state in responsive apps.

You can read about it here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

An example how you can manage a visible burger menu icon on small screens and an invisible on big screens could be as following:

```
<button class="visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">My Button</button>
```

That button would only be visible on small screens.

*EDIT*

To deal with the visiblity of your Menu I would suggest you to add classes to your Menu instead of using inline styling.

The pros of adding classes are:
You can easily style it in your stylesheet
It doesn't override any other stylings that come after this one

The cons of adding classes are:
You have to create a class in css ;) (which isnt a con)

Therefore I would go with this method to your `click function`

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById('hamburgermenu');
  if(e.getAttribute('class') == 'my-class my-visible-class') 
      e.setAttribute('class', 'my-class')
  else
      e.setAttribute('class', 'my-class my-visible-class')
  }
} // you also missed this closing bracket
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Thanks you for taking your time to explain the reasoning behind your solutions!

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer so that others know it helped you